# Need help understanding the embedded image

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, words, readings

Apologies for the blurry image, I've been trying to identify a location in a relatives photo and this sign appears to be the only hint I have at it. I'm afraid my grasp of written Japanese isn't quite strong enough to understand it though, would anyone here be able to decipher it for me?

[image: Sign]

Comment: Isn't that a Google Maps street view screenshot?

Comment: I've got some talking to do with uncle then it appears.

Comment: If your authority as somebody who understands some Chinese characters is on the line, you can tell that you saw 「天大橋」 and then you saw the (c)2015 Google watermark :P

Answer (score 5):

It says:

> 天大橋{てんだいばし}
>
> 昭和{しょうわ}５９年{ねん}１２月竣工{がつしゅんこう}

meaning:

"Tendai Bridge"

"Completed in December, Year 59 of Showa" ← That is 1984.

The bridge seems to be located in the City of Satsuma-Sendai in Kagoshima Prefecture unless there is a bridge with the same name somewhere else.